# Why Ruby extension(Peng Lv) does not work?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I am working on macOS Catalina versions 10.15.7.
I have a problem with Ruby(Peng Lv) extension for VScode. It seems it does work - no syntax highlighting except for the 'do', 'end', symbols ':', strings and comments.
Here is the list of all my extension:
endwise 1.4.2
Ruby(Peng Lv) 0,28,1
Ruby Solargraph 0,21,1
VSCode Ruby 0.28.0
vscodhe-icons 11.1.0

and my settings.json looks like this:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"explorer.compactFolders": false,
"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
"ruby.useBundler": true, // use the internal language server (see below)
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"ruby.format": true
}
```

I have tried installing many different version od Ruby(Peng Lv) extensions but nothing changed.I really don't know what is the issue. Do you know what should I do to resolve this annoying problem?

[image: Current syntax highlighting]

Answer (score 2):

In case someone came across that problem, all you have to do is change the VScode theme from Dark to Dark+.